# Is there any way to write a HQL query which needs to be executed through shell script where the task is to remove characters except A-Z0-9a-z,&-“#/;:

Tags: regex, shell, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I wish to write a HQL query which is executed through shell script.
The main purpose of the query is the data should not contain any characters other than A-Z, 0-9, space, and special characters other than comma, ampersand, dash, @ # / semicolon, colon.

Please find the query which i used to achieve my requirement although i was not 100% successful.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,'[^a-zA-Z \\-\\\']',''),'^[\\-\\\' ]*','')
from source_table
```

Please find the samples i used to test:

```
'Proa$$%%'  
'$%$%&'  
'$*&%$'  
',&-“#/;:$'  
'XYZ.'
```

Expected output is :

```
'Proa'  
'&'  
'&'  
',&-“#/;:’'  
'XYZ'
```

*Please help me in solving this requirement*

Answer (score 0):

Try with this **`(\\$|\\.|\\%|\\*)`** regex.

---

**`Example:`**

```
hive> select regexp_replace(name,"(\\$|\\.|\\%|\\*)","") from source_table;
```

**Output:**

```
Proa
&
&
,&-“#/;:
XYZ
```

The above query you can keep in shell script using `hive -e`.

```
hive -e 'select regexp_replace(name,"(\\$|\\.|\\%|\\*)","") from <db_name>.source_table'
```

**`Update:`**

```
select regexp_replace(name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9\\,\\:\\;\\&\\-\\#\\/]','') from <db_name>.source_table;
```

**Output:**

```
Proa
&
&
,&-#/;:
XYZ
```

Comment: This will work for the current source what happens if someother special character is provided other than the one mentioned above?I believe it won't work right.

Comment: @Prasu2690, Check my Updated answer to replace all characters except so any special character provided we will replace them dynamically.

Comment: @Prasu2690, If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 484.
It's working fine.
Only change i made to my script is instead of \ i added two more.Please find the below for the same.

```
select regexp_replace(name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\,\\\\:\\\\;\\\\&\\\\-\\\\#\\\\/]','') from <db_name>.source_table;
```

the above code works fine in my shell script.

Issue is resolved.